# public class TodolistFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnKeyListener{

Tags: android

I'm trying to make simple todolist inside Fragment class 
I dont have any errors but when I run the application it stops working as soon as I try to access todolist - I'm not sure which part I'm doing wrong

```
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): Process: com.projecttracker, PID: 7055
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.projecttracker.TodolistFragment.onCreateView(TodolistFragment.java:36)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.projecttracker.TodolistFragment.onCreateView(TodolistFragment.java:36)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f0a000c, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.projecttracker.TodolistFragment
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-04 18:42:29.487: E/AndroidRuntime(7055):     ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this in your onCreateView Method -

```
 super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

before you inflate it:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todolist, container,
                false);
```

Comment: could you add your xml file please :)

Comment: Thanks I had this code in my xml which I deleted and it solved the problem <fragment android:name="com.projecttracker.TodolistFragment" android:id="@+id/TodoListFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: nice, could you mark this as right answer please? :)

Answer (score 0):

In `fragment_todolist.xml` you have two view elements that have the same `android:id` value (duplicated on line #9).  Make them both unique

Comment: Thanks I had this code in my xml which I deleted and it solved the problem  <fragment android:name="com.projecttracker.TodolistFragment" 
        android:id="@+id/TodoListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />